# How can I publish my Tizen app from Xamarin forms visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tizen

I need to publish my first Tizen app to Tizen store but I don't know how to do that . when I did publish it show me some errors that prevent my app from working again.
also if I upload the .tpk file directly it show me another error about screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Tizen.Net is currently in preview version. Afaik currently you cant deploy Tizen.Net app in real device as current tizen devices are not "dotnet" enabled . Only you can run .net application in Emulator.

Ref: https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/tizen-.net/device-does-not-have-.net-installed

Currently to publish your app in tizen store you need to develop it in Tizen native or web language.

To know about publishing procedure, check the following link.

http://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/216754658-Publishing-To-The-Tizen-Store

To publish your Tizen app in store, you have to maintain its standard by following some predefined Tizen Store validation rules.

To know about validation rules, check the following validation guide

https://developer.tizen.org/sites/default/files/documentation/tizen_validation_guide_ver_1.4_140529.pdf

Comment: I am wondering if that is still the case considering the recent updates